# How to check options in an ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select

I have an array with checked options values.

I need to mark **checked** on my select options form using **checkeds** array returned from ajax.

```
var options = data.options;
var checkeds = data.checkeds;

$.each(options, function(i, item){
    $('#ajax_locals').append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text : item,
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#ajax_locals').append('<option value='+ i +' checked='+ checkeds[i] +'>'+ item +'</option>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:
I also added selected in addition to checked. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

The only thing I have added is

```
checkeds[i]
```

This will take the variable `i` from the loop and get the corresponding array index from `checkeds`

```js
var options = {
  0: "one",
  1: "two",
  2: "three"
};
var checkeds = {
  0: false,
  1: true,
  2: false
};

$.each(options, function(i, item){
    $('#ajax_locals').append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text : item,
        checked: checkeds[i],
        selected: checkeds[i] //Is this what you tried to achieve?
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="ajax_locals"></select>
</form>
```